Is it possible to conditionally skip assertions in playwright tests?
I would like to avoid adding the same if condition with assertion in different tests. Example:
if (flag === true) {
   expect(1+1, "Adding two ones.").toBe(2);
}

Is there a way to build the if condition in a central place and reuse, maybe like a custom matcher?

It's easy to skip tests, and long tests with lots of assertions is generally an antipattern. So can you break your tests into individual steps and assertions?
